# Why do I get "invalid pointer operation" when I rearrange a TObjectList?

Tags: delphi, list

Let's assume that I have the following custom list with the following declaration:

```
type 
  TCustomList = class(TObjectList)
  private
    function GetItem(AIndex: Integer): TMyObject; // virtual;
    procedure SetItem(Index: Integer; AObject: TMyObject);
...
  public
    property Items[Index: Integer]: TMyObject read GetItem write SetItem;
    procedure InsertSort();
  end;
```

With the following implementation:

```
implementation

function TCustomList.GetItem(AIndex: Integer): TMyObject;
begin
  Result := TMyObject(inherited Items[AIndex]);
end;

procedure TCustomList.SetItem(Index: Integer; AObject: TMyObject);
begin
    inherited Items[Index]:= AObject;
end;

procedure TCustomList.InsertSort;
var
  i, j: integer;
  key: TMyObject;
begin
  for j := 1 to self.Count - 1 do
  begin
    key:= self.Items[j];
    i := j - 1;
    while ((i >= 0) AND (self.Items[i].Compare(key)>0)) do
    begin
        self.Items[i+1]:= self.Items[i]; // does not WORK!!! properly.. System.Contnrs problem ?? 
        i := i-1;
    end; // while
    self.Items[i+1]:= key;
  end; // for
end; // procedure InsertSort
```

As I run the code over a collection of instances of `TMyObject`, I get an invalid-pointer-operation exception. This, I believe, is caused by poor reading and writing of the elements of the `TCustomList` via the `Items` property.

Why does this invalid-pointer-operation exception appear?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is happening here is that the ownership of the object list is getting in the way. Because you are using `TObjectList`, anytime the list is asked to forget about a member, it will destroy it. This happens in your code when you write:

```
self.Items[i+1] := ...
```

The member that is stored at index `i+1` before the assignment is destroyed to make room for the new item. Eventually you will end up destroying an object that has already been destroyed and that's when your invalid pointer exception occurs.

To solve the problem could make use of the `Extract` method which allows you to remove an item without destroying it. Or as @Arioch smartly points out in the comments, the `Exchange` method which is perfect for comparison sorts.

Even easier would be to temporarily switch `OwnsObjects` to `False` during your sort, not forgetting to restore it when you were done. Or perhaps you didn't even mean to use `OwnsObjects=True`. And in that case you want `TList` instead.

Frankly though you'd be far better off using the in-built `Sort` method that is originally exposed by `TList`. There's simply no need for you to implement a sort method on a class that already comes with a perfectly decent one.

Comment: Thank you! I also thought that TObjectList does exactly that, i.e, attempt to destroy the same object twice.  I will try your solution and post if it worked.

Comment: One solution, as you suggested: use the inbuilt TList.Sort function as follows: 
invoke 'myCustomList.Sort(@MyObject.Compare)' - with @MyObject.Compare being a pointer to the Comparison function implemented inside TMyObject.

The second approach I tried is:
invoke 
'self.OwnsObjects := false;'
before the for loop of TCustomList.InsertSort; and then 'self.OwnsObjects := true;' 
after the sorting is completed.

Thanks, David, I would have struggled a lot.

Comment: You need to implement the compare function as a standalone function rather than as an instance method. Your code calling `Sort` probably works, but that's a little bit by accident. One word of advice. Don't use `@` to obtain a function pointer.

Comment: there is also `TObjectLsit.Exchange` method, that can be used for sorting operations even with `OwnsObject` as true